# How to find out the maximum framerate of a webcamera?

Tags: webcam, framerate

How can I get maximum frame rate from a webcam?

Comment: More details would be useful, for instance what webcam model and what you're trying to do. Why is the frame rate limiting you? What is your OS?

Comment: I just wish to know what the maximum is; I actually am not sure what model it is, I was going to set a parallel question for finding that out. It just comes up generic. It looks like a C270 by Logitech though.

Comment: Try opening it as a stream using Media Player Classic, or VLC.

Comment: I'd start with the manual.

Comment: This isnt my webcam, and I dont have the manual, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... first...

> The QuickCapture software application video recording default is 15 FPS. This setting was chosen because Logitech feels that it provides the best overall image quality with reference to their RightLight™/RightLight™2 Technology.

And..

> In order to capture video at 30 FPS, third-party video recording software will be required.

Now, they go on to state what settings are necessary, how you would need to adjust the "shutter speed" (there is no actual shutter though), how using the Low Light Boost might severely drop the frame rate to as low as 5fps, etc. But, the important info.... well... read for yourself...

> A QuickCam® Pro 9000 can physically output 30 FPS at 640x480 resolution, 30 FPS at
>   800x600 resolution, and 15 FPS at 960x720 resolution (MJPG).
>
> For *most* applications, you will be limited to approximately 10 FPS (USB bandwidth limitation of 12 Mbps), unless your camera is detected as an Enhanced USB 2.0 device (480 Mbps).
>
> 160x120 x 24-bit color x 30 FPS x (format) = 9,216,000 bps(9.216 Mbps)
>
> 320x240 x 24-bit color x 9.766 FPS x (format) = 12,000,000 bps(12.000 Mbps)
>
> 640x480 x 24-bit color x 2.441 FPS x (format) = 12,000,000 bps(12.000 Mbps)
>
> 320x240 x 24-bit color x 30 FPS x (format) = 36,864,000 bps(36.864 Mbps)
>
> 640x480 x 24-bit color x 30 FPS x (format) = 147,456,000 bps(147.456 Mbps)
>
> 800x600 x 24-bit color x 30 FPS x (format) = 230,400,000 bps(230.400 Mbps)
>
> 960x720 x 24-bit color x 30 FPS x (format) = 331,776,000 bps(331.776 Mbps)
>
> 1280x960 x 24-bit color x 24.414 FPS x (format) = 480,000,000 bps(480.000 Mbps)

In short, it depends on the software you are using to take the video from the camera, the type of USB connection, the size of the image you are getting from the camera, and the capture settings WITHIN the software.

So... without more specific information from you, no more specific information could be given *to* you.

Read up.  http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Webcams/How-to-get-30-Frames-Per-Second-with-your-Logitech-Webcam/td-p/202898

Answer (score 16):

In Linux, assuming your webcam can be accessed via Video4Linux, use the command:

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
```

(If you have more than one video device, add the `-d <device>` option, where `<device` is the path to the device file, e.g. `/dev/video1`.

Sample output:

```
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Index       : 0
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
    Name        : YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
        Size: Discrete 160x120
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
        Size: Discrete 176x144
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
        Size: Discrete 352x288
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x720
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)

    Index       : 1
    Type        : Video Capture
    Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
    Name        : MJPEG
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
        Size: Discrete 160x120
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
        Size: Discrete 176x144
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
        Size: Discrete 352x288
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x720
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
```

(Note that these are values as advertised by the webcam and driver. Lots of factors may influence actual performance.)

In Windows / other OSes, please expand this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Are you saying that the webcam has no manufacturer markings on it at all, that could be used to figure out the exact product you have?

If it isn't built-in and if you haven't already done so, flip the webcam over and look for any part numbers that could be used to figure this out.

If it is built-in, then tell us what model of computer it is, and that should get us going down the right path.

In both cases, we can then figure out the specifications of the webcam, and also which drivers you need to download and install, so that your computer makes best use of the webcam and enables it to get the specified framerate.

Comment: So it can't be determined from Device Manager or something like that?